# How to represent a decision variable?

Tags: mathematical-modeling

I have an association matrix $n\times n$ where the values are either $0$ or $1$. So this matrix is called $B$ and $b(ij)$ is either $0$ or $1$ . However when $i=0$ this means something and if $i>0$ it means something else. How can I express this in a mathematical model?

Comment: I think you just did.

Comment: I mean representing it in a mathematical way that is without really explaining all this for example like this  \begin{cases}
      0, & \text{if i =0 case1}\  \\  0, & \text{if i >0 case2}\  \\
      1, & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}

Comment: I'm assuming, given the matrix of dimension $n\times n$, that both $1\leq i\leq n$, and $1\leq j\leq n$.  The indices of entry b( i, j ) give the ith row and the jth column of the entry, not the value of the entry.  So could you explain what you mean by the case in which $i = 0$?

Comment: @amWhy I actually considered that the indices start from zero so by i=0 and mean i=1

Comment: So if i=1 it represent something and if i >1 it represent something else. For example i=1 represent the column for a unique cat and i>1 represent the columns for the different dogs I have. If a1j =1 then this means that boy number j likes the cat  and if a(ij) =1 that means that the boy number j likes the dog number i

Comment: $i$ usually identifies the row of the matrix, j the column of the matrix.

Comment: @amWhy yes indeed